# Create New Order for New Customer

Tags: orders, customer, ce-1.8.1.0

I have added a custom attribute to the customer. This attribute is visible in grids and when you create / manage the customer from Customers / Manage Customers.

If you create a new customer via  New Order i need to add the field in the account information section between group and email.

I would like to use an observer rather than override the whole class. Is this possible.?

Comment: Is this for the admin side or front end?

Comment: This would be on the admin side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you will need to do is make sure your attribute has been set for all the forms under the table: `customer_form_attribute`

This table will have the attribute_id and the form_code. Form_code can be one of the following:

1. adminhtml_checkout
2. adminhtml_customer
3. adminhtml_customer_address
4. checkout_register
5. customer_account_create
6. customer_account_edit
7. customer_address_edit
8. customer_register_address

I guess in your case the attribute needs to be assigned to the form `adminhtml_checkout` and this can be done via a set-up script.

```
$oAttribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'your_attribute_code_here');
$oAttribute->setData('used_in_forms', array('adminhtml_checkout'));
$oAttribute->save();
```